# Have any two rovers launched from different crafts functioned in visible distance of each other?

Tags: rovers

Have any two rovers, launched on different spacecrafts, ever encountered each other and photographed the other?

Comment: I'd say it'd be unlikely since it makes more be as separated as possible, covering more area. Interesting question though, I think that's what NASA's trying to do with their martian sample return mission's.

Comment: These are different question, but somewhat related: [Can Curiosity pay InSight a visit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/32350) and [Can either Opportunity or Curiosity explore the state of Spirit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/8087)

Comment: It seems like you've answered that twice: in the question you have *"But who is this (center of cropped image)..."* that image isn't on Christie's auction. It's unrelated. If that image is part of your answer, you should move it there and let the question sit on its own: "Is there only one photo of Armstrong on the Moon?" You can cite Christie as the source of the claim. Separately, the question of who is in that cropped photo you have is totally off-topic there as that claim is your own, and was not made by a reputable source. It would *have* to be part of your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116198/discussion-between-evan-carroll-and-uhoh).